# ITP blocks Auth0 with auth0-react

Tags: reactjs, jwt, auth0

The Safari ITP blocks my Auth0 authentication in my React App, and it seems that Firefox is doing something similar.

I tried the various solutions such as using `useRefreshTokens="true"` in my `<Auth0Provider>` but I had to default to using localStorage (I am aware of the implications, but in a case of a XSS attack, using httpOnly token won't save you if the attacker wants to call your API anyway).

Is using the option `useRefreshTokens` and modifying the Application's parameter on the website enough to use it, or is it necessary to call a function from the library ?

The documentation and forums seem to be extremely lacking clarity in the way it works.

Comment: I have a similar problem on old versions of both firefox and edge (tested v17 and v18 of edge).
The login is successful but for some reason the react app enters an infinte redirect loop between react and auth0.
If you get it working please leave me a comment on how

Comment: @KaisBenDaamech Does it work with database user from Auth0 ?

Comment: No, I only use database users, and it doesn't work. I am suspecting that the problem is coming from the fact that I don't use a custom domain, maybe Edge blocks iFrame cookies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had so many drawbacks using Auth-0 and auth0-react that I'm probably gonna ditch it and do it myself.